# Merging / Adding 2 JSON File together using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, merge, addition

I want to combine following 2 JSON files below:

This is the first JSON File which is the original JSON file

```
{
    "toolcache": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "platform" : "linux",
            "platform_version": "22.04",
            "versions": [
                "3.7.*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "android": {
        "ndk": {
            "default": "23",
            "versions": [
                "21", "23", "24"
            ]
        }
    },
    "powershellModules": [
        {"name": "Pester"},
        {"name": "PSScriptAnalyzer"}
    ],
    "docker": {
        "images": [
            "alpine:3.14",
            "alpine:3.15",
            "buildpack-deps:buster",
            "buildpack-deps:bullseye",
            "debian:10",
            "debian:11",
            "moby/buildkit:latest",
            "node:14",
            "node:16",
            "node:14-alpine",
            "node:16-alpine"
        ]
    },
    "postgresql": {
        "version": "14"
    }
}
```

This is the second JSON File which we can update and we expect it to merge / add to the original first JSON File

```
{
    "toolcache": [
        {
            "name": "node",
            "platform" : "linux",
            "versions": [
                "16.*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "android": {
        "cmdline-tools": "latest",
        "platform_min_version": "27",
        "build_tools_min_version": "27.0.0",
        "extra_list": [
            "android;m2repository",
            "google;m2repository",
            "google;google_play_services"
        ],
        "addon_list": [
        ],
        "additional_tools": [
            "cmake;3.10.2.4988404",
            "cmake;3.18.1"
        ]
    },
    "powershellModules": [
        {"name": "MarkdownPS"},
        {"name": "Microsoft.Graph"}
    ],
    "docker": {
        "images": [
            "ubuntu:18.04",
            "ubuntu:20.04",
            "ubuntu:22.04"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the expected result:

```
{
    "toolcache": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "platform" : "linux",
            "platform_version": "22.04",
            "versions": [
                "3.7.*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "node",
            "platform" : "linux",
            "versions": [
                "16.*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "android": {
        "cmdline-tools": "latest",
        "platform_min_version": "27",
        "build_tools_min_version": "27.0.0",
        "extra_list": [
            "android;m2repository",
            "google;m2repository",
            "google;google_play_services"
        ],
        "addon_list": [
        ],
        "additional_tools": [
            "cmake;3.10.2.4988404",
            "cmake;3.18.1"
        ],
        "ndk": {
            "default": "23",
            "versions": [
                "21", "23", "24"
            ]
        }
    },
    "powershellModules": [
        {"name": "Pester"},
        {"name": "PSScriptAnalyzer"},
        {"name": "MarkdownPS"},
        {"name": "Microsoft.Graph"}
    ],
    "docker": {
        "images": [
            "alpine:3.14",
            "alpine:3.15",
            "buildpack-deps:buster",
            "buildpack-deps:bullseye",
            "debian:10",
            "debian:11",
            "moby/buildkit:latest",
            "node:14",
            "node:16",
            "node:14-alpine",
            "node:16-alpine",
            "ubuntu:18.04",
            "ubuntu:20.04",
            "ubuntu:22.04"
        ]
    },
    "postgresql": {
        "version": "14"
    }
}
```

I am not too sure if it is possible to add both JSON File together as I've only seen ways to merge while overwriting the existing JSON File. I have also tried Join Object and @($source; $extend) but it was not that simple as it would just create a duplicate.

I am try to experiment with Add-Member but I am now stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The expected JSON contains items that are in neither of the input files, e. g. `toolcache` -> `versions` -> `3.8.*`. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to **merge objects** and **append arrays**. For this I have slightly modified the code of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72521534/7571258) of mine:

```sh
function Merge-Json( $source, $extend ){
    if( $source -is [PSCustomObject] -and $extend -is [PSCustomObject] ){

        # Ordered hashtable for collecting properties
        $merged = [ordered] @{}

        # Copy $source properties or overwrite by $extend properties recursively
        foreach( $Property in $source.PSObject.Properties ){
            if( $null -eq $extend.$($Property.Name) ){
                $merged[ $Property.Name ] = $Property.Value
            }
            else {
                $merged[ $Property.Name ] = Merge-Json $Property.Value $extend.$($Property.Name)
            }
        }

        # Add $extend properties
        foreach( $Property in $extend.PSObject.Properties ){
            if( $null -eq $source.$($Property.Name) ) {
                $merged[ $Property.Name ] = $Property.Value
            }
        }

        # Convert hashtable into PSCustomObject and output
        [PSCustomObject] $merged
    }
    elseif( $source -is [Collections.IList] -and $extend -is [Collections.IList] ){

        # Output merged array, using comma operator to prevent enumeration 
        , ($source + $extend)

        # To remove duplicates, replace the previous line by:
        # , (($source + $extend) | Sort-Object -Unique)
    }
    else{
        # Output extend object (scalar or different types)
        $extend
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```sh
$data1 = Get-Content .\data1.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$data2 = Get-Content .\data2.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
Merge-Json $data1 $data2 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content merged.json -Encoding UTF8
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "toolcache": [
    {
      "name": "Python",
      "platform": "linux",
      "platform_version": "22.04",
      "versions": [
        "3.7.*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "node",
      "platform": "linux",
      "versions": [
        "16.*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "android": {
    "ndk": {
      "default": "23",
      "versions": [
        "21",
        "23",
        "24"
      ]
    },
    "cmdline-tools": "latest",
    "platform_min_version": "27",
    "build_tools_min_version": "27.0.0",
    "extra_list": [
      "android;m2repository",
      "google;m2repository",
      "google;google_play_services"
    ],
    "addon_list": [],
    "additional_tools": [
      "cmake;3.10.2.4988404",
      "cmake;3.18.1"
    ]
  },
  "powershellModules": [
    {
      "name": "Pester"
    },
    {
      "name": "PSScriptAnalyzer"
    },
    {
      "name": "MarkdownPS"
    },
    {
      "name": "Microsoft.Graph"
    }
  ],
  "docker": {
    "images": [
      "alpine:3.14",
      "alpine:3.15",
      "buildpack-deps:buster",
      "buildpack-deps:bullseye",
      "debian:10",
      "debian:11",
      "moby/buildkit:latest",
      "node:14",
      "node:16",
      "node:14-alpine",
      "node:16-alpine",
      "ubuntu:18.04",
      "ubuntu:20.04",
      "ubuntu:22.04"
    ]
  },
  "postgresql": {
    "version": "14"
  }
}
```

The output slightly differs from your expected output, but it looks like these are just minor mistakes on your side. Also, my function puts `android.ndk` at the beginning, as it is from the first file. This shouldn't matter, because the JSON standard doesn't specify the ordering of properties to be significant.

For detailed explanation of the code, see the answer linked at the top. The only difference here is the `elseif` branch, which appends arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your promp response zett42! That solves my question! Out of curiosity, is there a way to check if there is any duplicates which can be ignored / avoided? Also apology for my minor mistake on my result.json file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An example would be:
JSON1: 
` "docker": {
        "images": [
            "node:14",
            "node:16",
            "node:16-alpine"
        ]
    }`
JSON2:
` "docker": {
        "images": [
            "node:14",
            "node:16",
            "node:14-alpine"
        ]
    }`
Expected Result:
` "docker": {
        "images": [
            "node:14",
            "node:16",
            "node:16-alpine",
            "node:14-alpine"
        ]
    }`

Comment: @ChaMango This is possible, let me find some time later this day.

Comment: @ChaMango Replace the line `, ($source + $extend)` by `, (($source + $extend) | Sort-Object -Unique)`. I've also added it as comment in the code sample.

Comment: Hi @zett42, after attempting to merge using (($source + $extend) | Sort-Object -Unique) I noticed that the merged file did not correctly append the arrays. Instead it removed the array. `{
  "toolcache": {
    "name": "Python",
    "platform": "linux",
    "platform_version": "22.04",
    "versions": [
      "3.7.*"
    ]
`
The toolcache object is outside of the [ ] object and it is removed. I noticed that it did not merge with `"toolcache": [
 {
      "name": "node",
            "platform" : "linux",
            "versions": [
                "16.*"
            ]
        }`

Comment: @ChaMango As the array elements are not simple strings but objects, you must specify a sorting key: `, (($source + $extend) | Sort-Object -Property name -Unique)`. You might want to check the first array element to determine if it is an object: `if($source[0] -is [PSCustomObject]) { , (($source + $extend) | Sort-Object -Property name -Unique) } else { , (($source + $extend) | Sort-Object -Unique) }`.